# SonarEclipse plugin analysis using central SonarQube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

We want to set local analysis using SonarEclipse plugin for team of 50+ developers.
We currently have SonarQube server installed which is used by CI.
Can we use the same SonarQube server for the local analysis on developer boxes as installing sonarqube server locally on each box and keeping it in sync will be difficult?
Also what hardware requirements do we need to consider if we use same SonarQube server for CI and local analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys need something like [pre commit hook](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Pre-commit+Check).

Check this wiki - [sonar preview mode on local server](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Issues+Report+in+Preview+Mode)

Some of the important points from the wiki that are relevant to your use case -

> When running an analysis in preview or incremental mode, the SonarQube platform provides the ability to generate a report of issues so developers can see whether they're about to inject new technical debt before submitting their new code. This way, they can make sure they're not committing code with new issues, and therefore that no new technical debt will be reported on the SonarQube server after the next full analysis.

Also your CI server is not affected as mentioned in the wiki -

> You do not need to install a SonarQube server on your local machine. You only need to install your favorite analyzer (SonarQube Runner, Maven or Ant) on your local machine. In configuring the analyzer, you only have to set the sonar.host.url property to point to your remote SonarQube server. Connection settings for the SonarQube database aren't needed for preview analysis because no data is pushed to the database.

This way all the developers in your team will run the sonar analysis locally before committing their code, once the code is checked in (after developer is happy with the local analysis result) the central CI server will kick in to run the branch/trunk coverage and store the analysis report.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.If multiple developers are doing local analysis at same time, will that affect the performance of SonarQube?

Comment: IMO this should not affect the sonarqube performance. But I have never measured it; so its on you guys to test it out. Start with few and then scale on.. you can always monitor the system performance where soanrqube is deployed.